# Using Pillow/PIL with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to use a .png of a Tic Tac Toe board in Pygame so that the white part is transparent. However, I'm getting "libpng warning: sBIT: invalid" and the white is showing when I blit the board onto the background. The code is as follows:

```
background = pygame.image.load("blah.bmp")
board_surface = pygame.image.load("board.png")
board_surface.convert_alpha()
```

I read on the Pygame docs that only .bmp is guaranteed to work, and since image.get_extended() is returning a 1, I'm assuming that I simply don't have enough image processing support.

I've installed Pillows and imported the module, but I have no idea how to use this with Pygame. The tutorial shows how to load images as Pillow's Image class and so forth, but I need to represent images as Pygame's Surfaces.

I would appreciate any help with integrating these two things, or any other solutions on how to get my .png to work! For reference, I'm using Python3.3 and Pygame1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too. I solved it by switching to .tif (only with one f !). If you have Gimp installed use that to turn the white spaces into alpha=0 spaces (if you have problems doing that I can help with a more detailed explanation). After that import the image just as normal and use the .convert_alpha() method.